# Determine if the sequence converges, and if it converges find the limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $x_0 = 1$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{6}{1+x_n}$ for $n \geq 0$. Determine if the sequence converges, and if it converges find the limit.

I punched this series into a computer and it looks like it converges to $2$ but what steps should I take to write a formal proof? I appreciate any advice and tips you have for me and thank you in advance

Comment: If it converges, the limit is a solution of $L=6/(1+L)$

Comment: Can you show that it's an alternating sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f(x)=\frac{6}{1+x}$. We have that $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$. It's not hard to inductively see that $x_n=f^n(1)$.

It's not hard to see that for $x\geq 0$, $f(x)\geq 0$. This means that for $x\geq 0$, $f^n(x)\geq 0$. Note that $\frac{d}{dx} (f(f(x)))=f'(f(x))f'(x)$. It is clear that for all $x\geq 0$ we have $f'(x)\leq 0$, hence it follows that for all $x\geq 0$ we have $f(f(x))$ is strictly increasing.

Note that $x\leq f^2(x)\leq 2$ for all $x\in [0,2]$. So this means that for any arbitrary $x\in [0,2]$ we have that $x\leq f^2(x)\leq 2$. Moreover, since $f^2(x)$ is increasing, we can say that for any arbitrary $x\in [0,2]$ we have that $f^2(x)\leq f^4(x)\leq f^2(2)=2$. So it follows that the series $x_{2n}=f^{2n}(1)$ is monotonically increasing and bounded above by $2$. Hence it must converge to some value $L_0\in [1,2]$

From similar reasoning, it's not hard to see that we must have that $x_{2n+1}=f^{2n+1}(1)$ is monotonically decreasing and bounded below by $2$. So $x_{2n+1}$ must converge to some value $L_1\in [2,3]$

Since $f^{2n}(x)$ converges to $L_0$, we know that $L_0\in [0,2]$ must satisfy
$$f^2(L_0)=L_0$$
$$\frac{6(1+L_0)}{7+L_0}=L_0$$
$$6+6L_0=7L_0+L_0^2$$
$$L_0^2+L_0-6=0$$
$$L_0=-3,2$$
However, since $L_0\in [0,2]$, the only possibly solution is $L_0=2$. Similar reasoning gives that $L_1=2$. Since $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$ both converge to $2$, we have that $a_n$ converges to $2$.